# Insert one HTML element before another jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder how to insert an HTML element before another with jQuery. 
It is also important to be able to get the content of the new element out of an input.
Something like that, but working :

```
 var input = $("#theInput").val();

 var content = document.createElement("p");

 content.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input));

 $("div").insertBefore(content);
```

Comment: You mixed up the order, `$(content).insertBefore("div");`, or just `$("div").before(content);`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("div").prepend(content);
```

Answer (score 1):

See below example:

HTML Structure:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Greetings</h2>
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$( ".inner" ).before( "<p>Test</p>" );
```

Result (HTML):

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Greetings</h2>
  <p>Test</p>
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

Please see sample below, it takes value from text box and insert it before

HTML Structure:

```
<div id="content">
<input type="text" value="textboxvalue" > <br/><br/>
<span>Insert text box value befor this one</span>    
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
var inputval = $("#content input").val();
$( "#content span" ).before( "<p>" + inputval + "</p>" );
```

Comment: It's all well, like the other examples I found in google. But could you help me out by explaining how to add my input variable to that paragraph. Cause here it is being added to the html file like text, I don't know if it can be modified

Comment: I have added a new sample above in my comment, working jsfiddle link is http://jsfiddle.net/Np8U8/2/

Answer (score 0):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WJdqj/3/)

**Option 1 - Just using jQuery:**

```
var input = $("#theInput").val();
$("<p />")                       // Create a paragraph element.
    .text( input )               // Set the text inside the paragraph to your input.
    .insertBefore( $( "div" ) ); // Insert the paragraph before the div element(s).
```

**Option 2 - Modifying your code:**

```
var input = $("#theInput").val(),
    content = document.createElement("p");
content.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input));
$( content ).insertBefore( $( "div" ) );
```

**Option 2a - Or you can change the last line to:**

```
$( "div" ).before( content );
```